# Book (Novel) Layout

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I would be grateful for any advice please.
I would like to format section headings with the Mathilde font. However, I receive an the error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \scr@ttl@@extract.
Usage of package `titlesec' together(scrbook) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec) Using default spacing and no format.
Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec) Using default spacing and no format.
Activating an ugly workaround for a missing(scrbook) feature of package `titles`
```

Apart from the error, I notice that the font in the section is not changed to Mathilde.

I attach a MWE that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to show margins
\usepackage[baseline=18pt,lines=33]{grid}
\usepackage{lineno} % to show line numbers
\usepackage{lipsum} % to show dummy text 
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont\fontspec{Mathilde}}
\usepackage{titlesec}%Add space above chapter titles
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}     {\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{1pt}%Second number changes space amount
\begin{document}
\linenumbers % show line numbers
\section*{SECTION}
\vspace{0 mm}
\lipsum[1-50] % dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both `KOMA` and `titlesec` do sophisticated setups to the sectioning commands. Don't use both. Use one of them!

Comment: And if you are using KOMA, use KOMA! At least, you'll lose functionality otherwise. Also, don't do `\fontspec{}` repeatedly (in every section heading, effectively). Create a new family and then use that.

Comment: By the way, you didn't check your code compiled before posting it, did you?

Comment: Very many thanks. Apologies for not checking the code before posting! cfr what do you mean "create a new family...?"

Answer (score 2):

You get warnings if you use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. But the error message

> File ended while scanning use of \scr@ttl@@extract.

is caused by the combination of `titlesec` *and* `grid` with a KOMA-Script class. Note that `grid` redefines the commands `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` too. From the `grid.sty`:

```
%%  Sections
%
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-.999\baselineskip}%
                                   {0.001\baselineskip}%
                                   {\bfseries\mathversion{bold}}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                   {\baselineskip}%
                                   {-.35\baselineskip}%
                                   {\bfseries\unskip}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                   {\baselineskip}%
                                   {-.35\baselineskip}%
                                   {\itshape\unskip}}
```

This is also the reason why the font of your section title can not be changed by `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. You have to use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\mathilde\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont
]{section}
```

*after* loading `grid`. But then the KOMA-Script definition of the section title "wins".

I do not know why you are loading `grid`. But here is a suggestion without `titlesec`

```
\documentclass[openany,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to show margins

\usepackage[baseline=18pt,lines=33]{grid}
\usepackage{lineno} % to show line numbers
\usepackage{lipsum} % to show dummy text 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  prefixfont=\normalfont\huge\bfseries,
  font=\normalsize\rmfamily,
  beforeskip=38pt,
  innerskip=20pt,
  afterskip=1pt
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\mathilde\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont
]{section}


\begin{document}
\linenumbers % show line numbers
\chapter{Test}
\section{SECTION}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really want to use package `titlesec` (this is not recommended) load it *before* `grid`:

```
\documentclass[openany,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to show margins

\usepackage{titlesec}%Add space above chapter titles

\usepackage[baseline=18pt,lines=33]{grid}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{1pt}%Second number changes space amount
\usepackage{lineno} % to show line numbers
\usepackage{lipsum} % to show dummy text 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\mathilde\fontsize{40}{45}\selectfont
]{section}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers % show line numbers
\chapter{Test}
\section{SECTION}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```